# Need Data from multiple tables with between operator and range values

Tags: sql-server

I have a table 1 with the below columns

URL, ID

table 2 with

rang0 , range1 and value

ID column of table 1 will be in between range of table 2 range0 to range 1.

I need a result set of table 1 URL, ID and check the ID range in table 2 and get its corresponding value in table 2.

greatly appreciated if someone can send a query as example

Table 1 Data
ID URL 
10  google
11 yahoo
11 msn
12  google
13 yahoo
12 msn

Table 2

rangeo  range 2  value
1         11      valu1
11        12      valu2 
12        13      value3

The ID Column is not unique value, that means multiple ID's can fall in the same range in table 2

Comment: Please give expected output and format your sample data.  As it is currently displayed, it's not helpful.  (This still sounds like you just need a basic inner join operation.  You have not made it clear why an inner join is not sufficient.)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a simple join...

```
SELECT T1.URL, T1.ID, T2.Value
FROM Table1 as T1
INNER JOIN Table2 as T2 on T2.Range0 <= T1.ID and T2.Range1 >= T1.ID
```

This could join 1 row in Table1 to multiple rows in Table2.  But you did not give enough information to know whether or not that is expected.

Check out [this tutorial on SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_join.asp).

Comment: I have added additional information, ID column is not unique , that is same id can have same same or differnt URL